# change category id manually

Tags: database

I would like to match both production and development versions to have identical category ID's without having to import the db every time. In this case it's only one Category which is out of Sync. (category ID 130 should be 137)

Which statement should I use on the db? (mysql noob)

Comment: Good question. I'm very likely to need do this myself shortly.

Comment: Could you provide an update to this, or mark one of the answers as accepted if it helped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it, but you should take a database backup just in case. You might need to run each group separately.

```
// Update the Categories Table
UPDATE exp_categories
SET 'cat_id' = 137
WHERE 'cat_id' = 130


 // Update the Categories Field Table
UPDATE exp_category_field_data
SET 'cat_id' = 137
WHERE 'cat_id' = 130


// Update the Category Posts Table
UPDATE exp_category_posts
SET 'cat_id' = 137
WHERE 'cat_id' = 130
```

Comment: That's really close, but the column name is just `cat_id` -- it's **not** `exp_cat_id` . Also, cat_id is an integer, so no need to quote the values. E.g., UPDATE exp_categories
SET cat_id = 137 WHERE cat_id = 130; will do the trick.